# how to print each word in each line using linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

suppose there is a file like this..(6 Ids)

```
k0012, k0013

k40035, k3089

Glc, 3-PGA
```

I want to print each Ids in each line using linux terminal.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use tr:

```
tr ' ,' '\0\n' file
```

Or gnu-sed:

```
sed 's/, */\n/g' <file
```

Or gnu awk:

```
awk -F, '{print $1}' RS='[[:space:]]+' file
```

Comment: I'm surprised that you didn't suggest grep.

Comment: Since you didn't, I added one.

Comment: Yes I noticed, `grep` is simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP "\b[^\s,]*\b" inputfile
k0012
k0013
k40035
k3089
Glc
3-PGA
```

Answer (score 0):

From your "input" it is unclear if the IDs are separated by blanks or by blanks and commas. If the latter is true, you probably need to handle both:

```
tr ' ,' '\n\n' < myfile | uniq
```

(you'll need `uniq` to remove those excessive blank lines, although you might probably be better off by using `awk` for it):

```
tr ' ,' '\n\n' < myfile | awk 'NF > 0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you after  this? Using this input: `(6 Ids) k0012, k0013 k40035, k3089 Glc, 3-PGA`

```
$ awk -F'[, ]*' '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)print $i}' input
k0012
k0013
k40035
k3089
Glc
3-PGA
```

If the input instead is this:

```
k0012, k0013

k40035, k3089

Glc, 3-PGA
```

try:

```
$ awk -F'[, ]*' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}' input
k0012
k0013
k40035
k3089
Glc
3-PGA
```

...or of there's only 2 columns:

```
awk -F'[, ]*' '{printf("%s\n%s", $1, $2)}' input
```

Comment: no not only two columns, there are six to seven columns and many rows

Comment: @user2836170 - then try 2nd awk approach